# retrofit.RetrofitError: Failed to invoke public io.reactivex.Observable() with no args at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest

Tags: android, retrofit, android-networking, rx-java2

Any one explain this error why I'm getting ? and please provide solution as well.
Error getting on Retrofit1.9.0 and RxJava2 combination.

```
     ERROR: Call failed
       retrofit.RetrofitError: Failed to invoke public io.reactivex.Observable() with no args
       at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:400)
       at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240)
       at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:813)


My Code:



 LoginActivity.java:
     LoginService loginService = new LoginServiceImpl();
        loginService.authenticate(userName, password)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                            .subscribe(authInfoSubscriber);
```

The following code has convert response into pojo using Gson, after header parsed from http Response.

```
@Override
    public Observable<ResponseInfo> authenticate(String username, String password) {
        final Map<String, String> fieldMap = new HashMap<>();
        fieldMap.put("grant_type", "password");
        fieldMap.put("password", password);
        fieldMap.put("username", username);

        return Observable.defer(new Callable<ObservableSource<ResponseInfo>>() {
            @Override
            public ObservableSource<ResponseInfo> call() throws Exception {
                return loginServiceInternal.authenticate(fieldMap).map(new Function<Response, ResponseInfo>() {
                    @Override
                    public ResponseInfo apply(@NonNull Response response) throws Exception {
                        GsonConverter converter = new GsonConverter(new Gson());
                        // you would have to change this to convert the objects to list
                        AuthResponse authResponse = null;
                        try {
                            authResponse = (AuthResponse) converter.fromBody(response.getBody(),
                                    AuthResponse.class);
                        } catch (ConversionException e) {
                            Logger.e(TAG, "Authentication Object conversion error: " + e.toString());
                        }
                        List<Header> headers = response.getHeaders();
                        String authCookies = "";
                        for (Header header : headers) {
                            Logger.v(TAG, String.format("\nHeader Name: %s \n Header Value: %s",
                                    header.getName(), header.getValue()) + "\n\n");
                            if ("Set-Cookie".equalsIgnoreCase(header.getName())) {
                                authCookies += header.getValue() + "|";
                            }
                        }
                        if (null != authResponse) authResponse.data.authCookies = authCookies;
                        return (null != authResponse) ? authResponse.data : null;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Please provide you valuable suggestion/solutions. Thanks

Comment: Post your code here

Comment: why are you using such old version of Retrofit ?

Comment: We're in upgrade progress. We planned to upgrade RxJava2, Retrofit2 respectively.